# Pass variable to a form

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way to do the following in one line in addition to the form definition, instead of three? I find myself doing something like this quite frequently --

```
form = EmploymentForm(data=request.POST or None, request=request)

employment_object = form.save(commit=False)
employment_object.user = profile
employment_object.save
```

Thank you.

Can do this:

```
form = EmploymentForm(data=request.POST or None, request=request)
form.instance.user = profile
...
```

Comment: Override the form's `save` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could refactor it into a function.

```
def save_with_user(form, user):
    obj = form.save(commit = False)
    obj.user = user
    obj.save()

# ...
form = EmploymentForm(data=request.POST or None, request=request)
save_with_user(form, profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, afaik. I know i'll be getting a -1 for this answer.